# Where can we see the endpoint URL when we use @Webservice annotation

Tags: web-services

I am using @Webservice annotation to generate the jax-ws webservice.Below is the code which I am using.This is deployed on Weblogic app server. But I am not able to figure out what would be the endpoint URL? Please help.

```
 @WebService
public class Calculator {
    public Calculator(){
}

@WebMethod
public double sum(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint would be the application context root plus the class name since you did not specify any parameters in the @WebService annotation.

http://servername:port/context-root/Calculator?wsdl

Comment: Thanks Brian!! I had tried this URL and I am getting 404 error.Anything else I am missing? This project has been deployed on Weblogic

Comment: After deploying is the application showing in an Active state? Any errors or clues in the logs?